# (17.10) Log in goes back to log in.

Tags: login

I don't know what happened. Clearly some file got corrupted in my /home folder. 
As such when I type my password, the system tries to log me in (purple screen) then dumps me back to the log in screen.

I can log in on command line (alt+F2) and I can log in as a different user normally.

Only entry in jouranlctl -f I can find relevant to this is a failure to write ICEAuthority file (I've tried to chmod it to me again, but it still says cannot write).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**To check a common cause of this error...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

`ls -al /home/your_username/.*author*` # use the correct your_username

**If you see either of these files owned by root:root...**

```
-rw------- 1 root root 352K Apr 24 09:28 .ICEauthority

-rw------- 1 root root   58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

**Then...**

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # to mount the disk as read/write

`cd /home/your_username` # again, use the correct your_username

`sudo chown your_username:your_username .ICEauthority` # use correct your_username

`sudo chown your_username:your_username .Xauthority` # use correct your_username

`sudo chmod 600 .*author*` # change the file(s) permissions

`reboot`

**And retest your normal login.**

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it. All files owned by the correct user. 
I created a new user and was able to log in fine with the new user. Reboot, and I could no longer log in with the new user either. So I gave up and installed 18.04 from scratch (already had a backup).